# pyspark trim and split

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create an `ArrayType` from an `StringType` but I am unable to do a `trim` and `split` at the same time.

#### Create DataFrame

```
data = [
    (
        "1",
        "Example 1",
        "element1 | element two | element (three) ",        
    ),     
]
schema = StructType(
    [

        StructField("id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("name", StringType(), True),
        StructField("value", StringType(), True),
    ]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

#### What I try to do

```
df = (df.withColumn("value_array", 
                    f.trim(f.split(f.col("value"), "\|")
                                                 )
                                         )
                )
```

#### The error that I get

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'trim(split(`value`, '\\|', -1))' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'split(`value`, '\\|', -1)' is of array<string> type.;
```

#### Code that works but is not complete

```
df = (df.withColumn("value_arry", 
                    f.split(f.col("value"), "\|")
                    )
                )
```

#### The result I get

```
"[e1| e 2 | e3 ]" #These values contains spaces in 
 
+---+---------+---------------+-------------------+
| id|     name|          value|         value_arry|
+---+---------+---------------+-------------------+
|  1|Example 1|e1| e 2 | e3 3 |[e1,  e 2 ,  e3 3 ]|
|  2|Example 2|       e1 | e2 |        [e1 ,  e2 ]|
+---+---------+---------------+-------------------+
```

The result I would like to get would have each element without spaces

##### Spark Version 3.2.1

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform` function after split:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("value_arry", F.expr("transform(split(value, '[|]'), x -> trim(x))"))

df.show(truncate=False)
#+---+---------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
#|id |name     |value                                    |value_arry                              |
#+---+---------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
#|1  |Example 1|element1 | element two | element (three) |[element1, element two, element (three)]|
#+---+---------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Or split using regex `\s+\|\s+`:

```py
df = df.withColumn("value_arry", F.split("value", r"\s+\|\s+"))
```

Comment: Sometimes there are whitespaces before or after the | but not always. Should I use a regular expression that includes all the options? a regex like "\s*\|{1}\s*"

Comment: @jalazbe yes `\s*\|\s*` should work fine in this case